# Map not displaying when address is geocoded using Geocomplete

Tags: google-maps, z-index, geocomplete

My issue is when users enter their address (with autocomplete), the expected behaviour is that the map would display a marker on the address. But for some strange reason, the map does not display :(

Here is where my test environment is, please have a look:
http://mycanprev.com/onboard-test/

Click on the "Location" tab to get to the geocomplete portion. When you enter your address, it's suppose to display the map with the marker set on the entered address but it just displays a gray box instead of the map. 
The map seems to display fine on mobile though.

I think the issue might be with the z-index, but I'm not sure how to fix it :(

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of issue that caused the gray box in the maps. You can try this following solution:

- First, make sure that you used the correct Google Maps API, valid API Key and not deprecated function calls.
- Setting the zoom parameter correctly. Check this SO question [11749742](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749742/google-maps-api-v3-gray-box-no-map) and [5838333](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838333/how-do-i-fix-google-maps-api-v3-from-showing-up-as-a-gray-box).
- Check the size of your maps DIV element and css. Check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838580/google-map-comes-partially-grey-area-comes-instead-of-images-from-google-server) for that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention to my question. I tried setting the zoom and unfortunately it didn't work:(

One thing to note is that once I enter an address, the map is still displayed as a gray box but if you resize the window, the map appears!?